# correct a data conceptual model

Tags: sql, database, data-modeling

I have for homework to correct a data model in DB. I think I have Identified the errors (should be 5) and correct it. I asked my Tutor but he said he cann't say whether they are correct or not so according to my analyses I have the following conclusion any ideas or suggestions will be much appriciated. Thanks!!
[image]

1. One of the errors is inconsistancy of notations . It has been used
   Chen and Crows feet.
2. Second I thought InterviewDaYPerson should be named only person but
   not sure about this one.
3. Third Though Staff can have more than 2 interviews but it turned out
   to be correct.
4. Fourth Make a connection for Staff interviews a candidata
   relationship.
5. Fifht Staff is associated with InterviewDay.